# Is there a way to save macro script into a variable as string in Visual Basic?

Tags: vba

I want to write certain macro script in a cell as text. Googled, but I found nothing.

[image: Example]

Comment: https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s9/win002.htm

Comment: Please add more context.  Right now all we could know is you'd like to save some text in a cell which of course you can do.

Comment: I want to convert a script code into text. I can't think of anything other than post a picture showing it to be more clear.

Comment: It requires enabling the [Trust access to the VBA project object model](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/enable-or-disable-macros-in-office-files-12b036fd-d140-4e74-b45e-16fed1a7e5c6?redirectSourcePath=%252fen-US%252farticle%252fEnable-or-disable-macros-in-Office-documents-7B4FDD2E-174F-47E2-9611-9EFE4F860B12&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US#__toc311698313). It is a dangerous setting that should be kept disabled.

Comment: "VBA cannot parse VBA code", that's enough. I just wanted to know if there was a way to do it. I appreciate the time of all.

Comment: I don't believe there is a way to do this the way you are wanting to do it; like an `Eval()` or `Execute()` type function. You can evaluate an excel formula that is stored as a string with the `Evaluate` method of the `Application` object but that's not what you are asking. As @GSerg mentioned you can manipulate a VBProject with VBA, but I don't think you'll end up with exactly what you are shooting for.

Comment: You can put comment "flags" on either side of the code you want to extract, and use the VBA Extensibility library to scan for those lines.

Answer (score 0):

You could export your module to a file:

```
ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents(Module.name).Export ModuleFile
```

Then read that file in to a variable. Parse it, and do whatever you want with the text at that point. This requires programmatic access to VBA, which as @GSerg points out is a terrible idea. It opens you up to malware VBA code attacks.

Comment: Note: the "parse it" part is far from trivial, and IME+IMO doomed if done in VBA.

Comment: Indeed, working this way is not a good idea. I was really just searching for more information reggarding this. I'm manually copying the part of the code I want to save. The bad part is: everytime I change the codes, I will have to manually copy them again.